# array_merge all except for one key/value pair? PHP

Tags: php, array-merge

I'd like to merge two user objects (one is a duplicate). The problem is, one user object has some fields the other doesn't and vice versa. I'd like to `array_merge` all the key/value pairs except for the `id`. Is there anyway to do this?

Here is my code below. When I try to merge, the `$second_user` doesn't delete like I would like it to. If I comment out the merge block, it deletes duplicates properly without merging. However, when I comment it back in, there are still duplicates.

I think the issue is trying to use `array_merge` when `id` is an immutable field.

```
 public function combine($first_user, $second_user)
{
    // Always make sure $first_user is the "original" user that we're going merge.
    if ($first_user->created_at > $second_user->created_at) {
        $tmp = $second_user;
        $second_user = $first_user;
        $first_user = $tmp;
    }

    // Merge their data and save to the first user
    $updated_user = array_merge(array_filter($second_user->toArray()), array_filter($first_user->toArray()));
    $first_user->fill($updated_user)->save();

    $second_user->delete();
}
```

Comment: Please add an example with input, current output (**+ your code**) and expected output

Comment: Yes sorry - will update now!

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if I understood correctly, but checkout my answer below, if I didn't quite get what you are trying to do, I'll update or delete the answer...

Answer (score 1):

Just unset the id after the merge:

```php
$array = array_merge($arr1, $arr2);
unset($array['id']);
```

Comment: I'm getting an error that I can't merge because `id` is an immutable field so this wont' work :-/

Comment: If there are immutable fields, then they're not arrays.

Comment: They're user objects that I want to merge - I changed them into arrays (noted in the code above). Besides `array_merge` are there better ways to combine the user data?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if I understood correctly, but if you wan't to achieve the following:

- use ***$first_user*** var as the "main" var for storing data
- and preserve ***$first_user*** var data (including ID)
- and add fields of ***$second_user*** to the ***$first_user*** while preserving existing ***$first_user*** data

If thats the case, instead of array_merge just use array ***+*** operator:

```
$arr1 = array_filter($first_user->toArray());
$arr2 = array_filter($second_user->toArray());
$updated_user = $arr1 + $arr2; // union
```

> The + operator returns the right-hand array appended to the left-hand array; for keys that exist in both arrays, the elements from the left-hand array will be used, and the matching elements from the right-hand array will be ignored.